# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException for Razor Pages deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core

After deploying my application to Azure I get the following error for my Razor Pages that have both a page and folder with the same name.

Locally the url **/team** routes to **/pages/team.cshtml** and **/team/john-doe** routes to **/pages/team/index.html**

It appears as if the routing is not regarding the

```
@page "{name}"
```

directive in the **Index.cshtml** file

The pages run fine locally.

```
2018-12-19 16:37:16.6277|Default|0HLJ5Q03CULHJ:0000001A||Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector|ERROR|Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity. Matching actions: Page: /Team
Page: /Team/Index 
2018-12-19 16:37:16.7644|Default|0HLJ5Q03CULHJ:0000001A||Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|ERROR|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Page: /Team
Page: /Team/Index
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext context, IReadOnlyList`1 candidates)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Middleware.ImageSharpMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext context, IReadOnlyList`1 candidates)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Middleware.ImageSharpMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Did you publish to Azure App Service or Azure VM? Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Azure App Service. The problem seems to the that the route template is not recognised so the two routes cannot be disambiguated